# Calculating categorical average with filtered data

Tags: r

I have following dataset:

```
A -1
A 10
B  8
D -1
A  0
A  4
B  2
C  6
```

And I want to add column to it like this:

```
A -1 4,6
A 10 4,6
B  8 5,0
D -1 5,0
A  0 4,6
A  4 4,6
B  2 5,0
C  6 6,0
```

What have happened here?

Well I have calculated average of each categorical letter variable but ignoring negative numbers and given this as new columns value.

If there is only negative values for category I have given value of total average (ignoring negative values).

In SQL this would have been done with filtered group funcion followed with join. In excel this would be conditional vlookup. How I do this in R?

**Edit:**

```
# Create dataset
category <- c("A","A","B","D","A","A","B","C")
value <- c(-1,10,8,-1,0,4,2,6)
dataset <- data.frame(category, value)

# Calculated means

fdata <- dataset[dataset[,'value']>-1,]
aggregate(fdata[,2], list(fdata$category), mean)
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `ave` from base R grouped by each `category`, we check if `all` the `value` in a particular group is less than 0, if it is then we select the `mean` of the entire `dataset` and if it is not then we take only the `mean` of the group.

```
dataset$mean_column <- with(dataset, ave(value, category, FUN = function(x) 
         ifelse(all(x < 0), mean(value[value >= 0]), mean(x[x >= 0]))))

dataset

#  category value  mean_column
#1        A    -1    4.666667
#2        A    10    4.666667
#3        B     8    5.000000
#4        D    -1    5.000000
#5        A     0    4.666667
#6        A     4    4.666667
#7        B     2    5.000000
#8        C     6    6.000000
```

Answer (score 3):

Using dplyr

```
dataset %>% 
  mutate(
    x = ifelse(value < 0, NA_integer_, value),
    meanAll = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
  mutate(meanGroup = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE),
         meanGroup = ifelse(is.nan(meanGroup), meanAll, meanGroup))

# Source: local data frame [8 x 5]
# Groups: category [4]
# 
# # A tibble: 8 x 5
#   category value     x meanAll meanGroup
#     <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1        A    -1    NA       5  4.666667
# 2        A    10    10       5  4.666667
# 3        B     8     8       5  5.000000
# 4        D    -1    NA       5  5.000000
# 5        A     0     0       5  4.666667
# 6        A     4     4       5  4.666667
# 7        B     2     2       5  5.000000
# 8        C     6     6       5  6.000000
```

Answer (score 2):

The OP has written *In SQL this would have been done with filtered group funcion followed with join.* This approach can be implemented with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
# filter data and compute group means 
setDT(dataset)[value >= 0, .(grp.mean = mean(value)), category][
  # now join with dataset
  dataset, on = "category"][
    # fill empty group means with overall mean of filtered values
    is.na(grp.mean), grp.mean := dataset[value >= 0, mean(value)]][]
```

which returns

```
   category grp.mean value
1:        A 4.666667    -1
2:        A 4.666667    10
3:        B 5.000000     8
4:        D 5.000000    -1
5:        A 4.666667     0
6:        A 4.666667     4
7:        B 5.000000     2
8:        C 6.000000     6
```

---

Here is a more concise variant which uses assignment by reference and avoids the join operation (I'm not sure which one is faster):

```
library(data.table)
# assign by reference of computed group means of filtered values
setDT(dataset)[, grp.mean := mean(value[value >=0]), category][
    # fill empty group means with overall mean of filtered values
    is.na(grp.mean), grp.mean := dataset[value >= 0, mean(value)]][]
```